# How to merge a ZodEffect with a ZodObject

Tags: typescript, zod

I have two schemas, I would like to re-use the first schema in the second schema, this works fine when the first schema does not use the refine nor super-fine methods. According to the documentation, this should be possible by simply passing the second schema as an argument for the `merge` method in the first schema. I receive a type error saying that the first schema is of type `ZodEffects`, is there a way to infer the underlying object?

```js
import { z } from 'zod';

const FirstSchema = z.object({
  name: z.string().min(1),
});

const SeccondSchema = z
  .object({
    lastname: z.string().min(1),
  })
  .refine((data) => data.lastname.includes('foo'));

const MergedSchema = FirstSchema.merge(SeccondSchema); // <-- How to convert ZodEffect to ZodObject?
```

Here's an example in Stack Blitz with my error:  https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-r9on2v?file=index.ts

Answer (score 1):

Solved by using the `innerType` method

```js
const MergedSchema = FirstSchema.merge(SeccondSchema.innerType());
```